# Rsync and df/du commands output different sizes for source

Tags: rsync, disk-usage

I'm syncing three drives with a remote nfs share with rsync. Before starting, I analyze all disks with the following commands:

`rsync -avn --delete --human-readable --stats dir1/ dest/`

`rsync -avn --delete --human-readable --stats dir2/ dest/`

`rsync -avn --delete --human-readable --stats dir3/ dest/`

and at the end of the outputs, rsync tells the total size of the files to be transferred.

Problem is, these 3 disk's capacity is a total of 6TB. Rsync tells me it will transfer 5.9TB of data. But when I execute df and du, I see a total of 2.7 TB used space in these 3 disks. So rsync claims it will transfer more space that I can see on the filesystem and I'm all O.K with that, but I'm logging my transfers for future reference and this difference is really annoying.

I've searched for a solution a lot and looked for hard and symlinks only to find none. Can anyone explain this difference.

P.s. The source dirs are vmfs partitions. And the transfer operation is a fresh one, so the target share is empty.

Comment: Try adding `-HS` to preserve hardlinks and sparse files.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. rsync with -HS parameter results the same. I also did a search with `find` and `ls`. There are not any hardlinked or sparse files.

Comment: If you run those commands without the `-n` (`--dry-run`) flag, all with the same `dest/` destination, you'll lose the copies from `dir1` and `dir2` as you copy `dir3`. Is that an artefact of the example or real but unintended consequence?

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, I ran rsync with `avn` flags. My copies in `dir1` and `dir2` are intact, I'm sure of it because I mounted them `ro`. After your suggestion I ran rsync with `-avn -HS`, but it resulted the same.

Comment: @roaima's point is that `--delete` deletes files in `dest/` that are not in the source. So (1) you `rsync` from `dir1` to an empty `dest`, everything's fine, but (2) you rsync from `dir2` to `dest` after that, everything that was previously copied to `dest` but isn't in `dir2` will be deleted. Ditto for whatever was copied from `dir2` when you `rsync` from `dir3`.

Comment: Indeed. If you run these commands in order, then after the last one you will have copied the contents of `dir1`, `dir2` and `dir3` to `dest` BUT the second and third operations will mean that you will also have deleted the copies of `dir1` and `dir2` from `dest`, leaving only the copy of `dir3` there